# Node JS Form Sumit using Ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am new in Node JS , I want to submit a form using ajax like all we are doing in PHP/CakePHP but here i am facing a problem.

**HTMl code**

```
<form role="form" action="javascript:;" id="myform">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="enter">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

**My AJAX code is**

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = $('#myform').serialize();
          $.ajax({ 
              url: '/ajax',
              type: 'POST',
              cache: false, 
              data: JSON.stringify(data),
              contentType: 'application/json',
              success: function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                   alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err);
               }
            })
          });
```

**app.js code**

```
app.post('/ajax', bodyParser(), function (req, res){

  var obj = {};
  console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

  var input = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  var data = {

      name    : input.name,
      email   : input.email
  };

  var query = db.query("INSERT INTO users set ?",data, function(err, rows){
  console.log(query.sql);
      if (err)
          console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );
         res.send({'success' : true, 'message' : 'Added Successfully'});
  });


});
```

But when i submit this form then it generate an error in node console like

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token "
   at parse (D:\man_node\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: i cannot find the line. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think that, I am not 100% sure, that you should replace `var data = $('#myform').serialize();` with `var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();`

Comment: OMG , this is what i am forgetting to add. thank you so much.

Comment: but i am no longer to insert into database. nothing is inserting in db. :(